# I upgraded React Native to the latest version and now my Stack.Screens are throwing TypeScript error when I try to pass some components to them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I upgraded React Native from 0.69.7 to 0.72.3 and now when I try this:

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={Home}
/>
```

The component prop is being underlined and I receive the following TS error:

```
React component to render for this screen.

Type 'FunctionComponent<ScreenProps>' is not assignable to type 'ScreenComponentType<ParamListBase, "Home"> | undefined'.
  Type 'FunctionComponent<ScreenProps>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<{}>'.
    Types of parameters 'props' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'ScreenProps'.ts(2322)
types.d.ts(318, 5): The expected type comes from property 'component' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RouteConfig<ParamListBase, "Home", StackNavigationState<ParamListBase>, StackNavigationOptions, StackNavigationEventMap>'
```

My Home component looks like this:

```
type ScreenProps = StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Home'>;

const HomeScreen: FunctionComponent<ScreenProps> = ({ route }) => {
    return (
        <Container>
            <BodyText>Home</BodyText>
        </Container>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

Any idea why is this suddenly happening as it was working fine before. I upgraded react-navigation/native and react-navigation/stack to the latest versions too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this [section](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-screens) in your navigation.ts file then import `RootStackParamList` from that file

```
    import type { NativeStackScreenProps } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
                
    type RootStackParamList = {
    Home: undefined;
    Profile: { userId: string };
    Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
    };
        
type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'>;
```